# Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare() Error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html5-video

I have installed html5 video player plugin in wordpress it is showing the following error. Please let me know how can I fix it.

```
   Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs
 \wordpress\wp-content\plugins\lbg-vp2-html5-bottom\lbg-vp2-html5-bottom.php on 
 line 373   and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 990

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress
\wp-content\plugins\lbg-vp2-html5-bottom\tpl\players.php on line 41
```

Comment: It would help to code context for both messages.

Comment: Can't the [author](http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-video-player-wordpress-plugin/discussion/1613464?page=3) offer some feedback? Did you [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) your installation? Other [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) info?

Answer (score 1):

`$wpdb->prepare` works like `sprintf` or `vsprintf`. It should have a string followed by a variable number of parameters.

```
$wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title = %s",
    'My Great Title'
);
```

It used to just pass data through if the second parameter was missing so you could do things like this:

```
$wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title = 'My Great Title'"
);
```

It defeats the point of `prepare` but it worked and people did it-- maybe just out of habit, maybe out of a misunderstanding of what `prepare` is for. [Recent changes have altered that behavior and it now fails with an error](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).

Admittedly, I am guessing but I think that is the problem you are seeing.